# Thymeleaf - Chrome doesn't see css file

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

Tell my, why my browser don't see my css file?
I use spring boot and thymeleaf :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
```

my css file is on resources/static/css
and my templates are on resources/templates

When i click "chrome" icon in InteliJ, everything is working properly offline, but when i run my application, css is not loaded.

Comment: Use  `href="/resources/static/css/style.css"`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `href="../static/css/style.css"`

Try with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
```

Comment: Oh.. nevermind.. problem was in spring security.. i forgot unblock resources. Thanks for helping !